# Merging branch - merge too large to display but only one file has been changed?

Tags: merge, branch

I have created a branch feature/cms-wysiwyg-fix from master branch. FYI we have a branch for each of our environments so master, test and dev.

So in feature/cms-wysiwyg-fix branch I have committed and pushed one file -  storage.php

When I try to merge feature/cms-wysiwyg-fix into dev branch it is saying merge too large to display.

However if I go to merge feature/cms-wysiwyg-fix into test or master branch it displays the modified file storage.php as the only difference.

If I go to merge dev branch into test or master there is no difference?

So I am not sure why the merge is too large too display when I try to merge feature/cms-wysiwyg-fix branch into dev branch ?

Comment: Did you add `storage.php` as a new file, or, if not, how many lines of code did you change in that file?

Comment: Yes it was a completely new file, 538 lines of code in total.

Comment: Then the diff is 538 lines.  Most likely the tool you are using to view the diff cannot show this much, that is all.

Comment: I am using Bitbucket, that doesn't explain why trying to merge into test or master can display the difference?

Comment: Actually in Sourcetree I can see the difference, and it seems to be every file in the branch has been committed? Not sure how can this can be!